# How to convert BigQuery Standard SQL script into PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a BigQuery script to build geometrical progression from min term to max value using dense as ratio. It works in BigQuery very well but I want to use it in PostgreSQL.

```
WITH calc as (SELECT 0.02 as min_cpm, 9.8 as max_cpm, 1.6 as dense)      
SELECT min_cpm, max_cpm, dense, stage + 1 stage, 
IF (MOD(CAST(FLOOR(min_cpm * POWER(dense, stage)*1000) AS INT64),10)= 0, (CAST(FLOOR(min_cpm * POWER(dense, stage)*1000) AS INT64)+1 )/1000, CAST(FLOOR(min_cpm * POWER(dense, stage)*1000) AS INT64)/1000) as cpm,     
FROM calc,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, CAST(FLOOR(LOG(max_cpm/min_cpm) / LOG(dense)) AS INT64))) stage
```

This script rounds each `cpm` value out to three characters after the dot. And makes last character not equal `0`.

So expected output:

[image]

Is it possible to make it in PostgereSQL? Any suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very arcane.  But something like this:

```
with calc as (
      SELECT 0.02 as min_cpm, 9.8 as max_cpm, 1.6 as dense
     )      
select calc.*, stage + 1,
       FLOOR(min_cpm * POWER(dense, stage)*1000) / 1000
from calc cross join
     generate_series(0, ceiling(LOG(max_cpm/min_cpm) / LOG(dense)), 1) stage ;
```

Comment: I want to have last term less then max cpm value. How to modify it?

Comment: @Timogavk . . . Subtract 1 from the second argument in the `generate_series()` (although `floor()` might also do what you want).